# How do I send & receive messages in pidgin with python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instant-messaging, pidgin

I'm trying to make a game in python 3 for a friend of mine and I want to send multiplayer data safely and easily through an instant messaging software. Is there any way I can send and receive messages with python 3 in pidgin? If you can think of another IM app that will work and doesn't have a spam prevention or cooldown then that would be much appreciated.